# How can i change CMFC button Style

Tags: button, mfc

I have problem with CMFC button style. when I set style to style3d everything shown correctly in design mode but after running the style changed.(according to picture).

in design mode:

[image: image 1]

after running project:

[image: image 1]

I am using vs2010 on windowsXP

Answer (score 2):

You have no manifest for Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.

You find tons of links like [that](http://www.jose.it-berater.org/visualstyles/pages/enabling_visual_styles.htm).